# How to unnormalize (backtransform) variable after using recipes in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am training a `neuralnet` using `train` function and pre-processing the data using `recipes`.

Is there any function to make predictions from the model and then re-scale them in their original range, which is `[1, 100]` in my case?

```r
library(caret)
library(recipes)
library(neuralnet)

# Create the dataset - times table 
tt <- data.frame(multiplier = rep(1:10, times = 10), multiplicand = rep(1:10, each = 10))
tt <- cbind(tt, data.frame(product = tt$multiplier * tt$multiplicand))

# Splitting 
indexes <- createDataPartition(tt$product,
                              times = 1,
                              p = 0.7,
                              list = FALSE)
tt.train <- tt[indexes,]
tt.test <- tt[-indexes,]

# Recipe to pre-process our data
rec_reg <- recipe(product ~ ., data = tt.train) %>%
  step_center(all_predictors()) %>% step_scale(all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_center(all_outcomes()) %>% step_scale(all_predictors())

# Train
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 3,
                              savePredictions = TRUE)

tune.grid <- expand.grid(layer1 = 8,
                         layer2 = 0,
                         layer3 = 0)

# Setting seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12)
tt.cv <- train(rec_reg,
               data = tt.train,
               method = 'neuralnet',
               tuneGrid = tune.grid,
               trControl = train.control,
               algorithm = 'backprop',
               learningrate = 0.005,
               lifesign = 'minimal')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `step_normalize` instead of `step_scale` and `step_center`, you can use the following functions to "un-normalize" based on a `recipe`. (If you prefer two steps to normalize you will need to tweak the `unnormalize` function.)

This function is used to extract the relevant step.

```
#' Extract step item
#'
#' Returns extracted step item from prepped recipe.
#'
#' @param recipe Prepped recipe object.
#' @param step Step from prepped recipe.
#' @param item Item from prepped recipe.
#' @param enframe Should the step item be enframed?
#'
#' @export
extract_step_item <- function(recipe, step, item, enframe = TRUE) {
  d <- recipe$steps[[which(purrr::map_chr(recipe$steps, ~ class(.)[1]) == step)]][[item]]
  if (enframe) {
    tibble::enframe(d) %>% tidyr::spread(key = 1, value = 2)
  } else {
    d
  }
}
```

This function is used to un-normalize. So it multiplies the std. deviation and adds the mean.

```
#' Unnormalize variable
#'
#' Unormalizes variable using standard deviation and mean from a recipe object. See \code{?recipes}.
#'
#' @param x Numeric vector to un-normalize.
#' @param rec Recipe object.
#' @param var Variable name in the recipe object.
#'
#' @export
unnormalize <- function(x, rec, var) {
  var_sd <- extract_step_item(rec, "step_normalize", "sds") %>% dplyr::pull(var)
  var_mean <- extract_step_item(rec, "step_normalize", "means") %>% dplyr::pull(var)

  (x * var_sd) + var_mean
}
```

So you should be able to generate predictions and then use:

```
unnormalize(predictions, prepped_recipe_obj, outcome_var_name)
```

where `predictions` is a vector of predictions generated from the trained model, `prepped_recipe_obj` is `rec_reg` in your case, and `outcome_var_name` is `product` in your case.

Comment: You might also be interested in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/264).